# for...in loop with jQuery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, for-in-loop

I'm still new to learning loops so I'm a little confused. I have a `for...in` loop that loops a json file of objects. Then I have jQuery create some html elements for each object. I have one problem though, every time it loops, it repeats the previous objects along with the new one so the output becomes:

```
-name

-name
-test

-name
-test
-someone

-name
-test
-someone
-something
```

But I'm trying to do

```
-name

-test

-someone

-something
```

How can I achieve this?

My current code for it is this:

```
var html = ""
for (var name in urls) {
    html += `<div class='card-panel white'><div class='container'><div class='row'><div class='input-field col s12'> ${name} <br> ${urls[name].url} </div></div></div></div>`
    $("#main").append(html)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are appending HTML string on each iteration instead append entire code outside the for loop. Although use **[`Object#hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)** for getting only [own properties and not its prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Iterating_over_own_properties_only).

```
var html = ""
for (var name in urls) {
  if(urls.hasOwnProperty(name))
    html += `<div class='card-panel white'><div class='container'><div class='row'><div class='input-field col s12'> ${name} <br> ${urls[name].url} </div></div></div></div>`;
}
$("#main").append(html)
```

---

I think it would be better to use **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** and **[`String#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** methods.

```
$("#main").append(
  Object.keys(urls).map(function(name){
    return `<div class='card-panel white'><div class='container'><div class='row'><div class='input-field col s12'> ${name} <br> ${urls[name].url} </div></div></div></div>`;     
  })
)
```

Comment: `${name}` How does this part works? Any new arrival to ES6? Can you link me to the relevant doc?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Yes, that's a feature of *template strings*, which the OP used.

Comment: I feel extremely dumb now. @RajaprabhuAravindasamy template strings are so much better than the vanilla way in terms of productivity. Thank you for the answer. Will mark the answer correct when it lets me (time limit).